# Border around artwork when exporting Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, export, artboard, clipping-mask

I've had a continual issue with exporting Illustrator documents and getting a border around the artwork.

[image]

See image attached.

The artboard is 1080 x 1080 pixels. I created a background box filled with pink colour at 1080 x 1080 pixels, placed all the contents, then created a clipping mask using a 1080 x 1080 square shape. All aligned to artboard. The left hand side has no gap but the right hand side has a small gap (as you can see from this png) and I can't work out how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clipping mask does not help, unless all your shapes are absolutely, mathematically sticking to the artboard edges, which is likely not happening just by looking at your image. Even with mathematically placed shapes and mask, there is still a chance of getting side borders.

What you need to do is:

- remove the clipping mask and let everything flow freely outside the artboard
- keep the pink background box, but enlarge it, so it goes outside the arboard on all sides
- save again to PNG using the 'Clip to artboard' feature in the 'Save for web' panel

[image]